# Pdf encoded in iso-8859-1

Tags: python, pdf, iso-8859-1

How can i read text from pdf file encoded in 'iso-8859-1' in python ?

I  am trying to convert pdf to txt using textract in python but with certain files i am facing "unicodeDecodeError utf-8  codec cant decode byte 0xe2 in position 11 : invalid continuation byte". I think the file is iso-8859-1 encoded.

```
File "/home/kanika/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-. 
packages/textract/parsers/__init__.py", line 77, in process
return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
File "/home/kanika/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-. 
packages/textract/parsers/utils.py", line 46, in process
byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
File "/home/kanika/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-. 
packages/textract/parsers/txt_parser.py", line 9, in extract
return stream.read()
File "/home/kanika/mypython/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in 
decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 
 11: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show a complete code snippet that we can run and examine for ourselves. Make it a short snippet that shows your problem. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, are you committed to using `textract`? There are other packages designed for getting text from pdf files that could handle the encoding issue.

Comment: *"Pdf encoded in iso-8859-1"* - pdf is a binary format. Add a whole a pdf is never *encoded in iso-8859-1* (or in utf-8 or in whichever character encoding you think of). Each font in a pdf defines its own encoding for text drawn using it, and this encoding can be **WinAnsiEncoding** which is pretty near to iso-8859-1. If the font properly declares this, though, any commonly used text extractor supports this font encoding. So most likely your pdf contains a font the encoding of which simply is not or incorrectly declared. For further analysis please share the pdf in question.

Comment: not committed to use textract .the pdf in consideration is a malicious file

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work if you want to use textract

```
text = textract.process("yourFile.pdf")
```

Here `text` will contain all the text in the pdf.

Then you can write it into a new txt file as you wish.

Comment: This is the same process i am currently opting .... And it flashes above mentioned erroe